# WebForms - Custom Validator No Longer Working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

In my WebForms application I have a `CustomValidator` control. This control executes a JavaScript function that I created. If this function returns false, the form won't submit. This validator is used with the standard `RequiredFieldValidator` and `RegularExpressionValitors`.

This used to work perfectly fine, however, now, even if the JavaScript function returns `false`, the page will still submit. For some reason the `CustomValidator` is being ignored. As long as the `RequiredFieldValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator` controls pass, the page will submit, even though the JavaScript function displays the errors on submission.

I have debugged the JavaScript function and it is definitely returning `false`. I didn't use any server side code with my `CustomValidator`.

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm() {
    if (document.getElementById("DDApplicationID").selectedIndex > 0
        && document.getElementById("div_applicationType").style.display != "none") {
        return true;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("DDApplicationID").selectedIndex > 0) {
        var valid = true;

        ((validateTrainStation() == false) ? valid = false : valid);
        ((validateSupportType() == false) ? valid = false : valid);
        ((validateHomeStatus() == false) ? valid = false : valid);
        ((validateOtherNationality() == false) ? valid = false : valid);
        ((validateOtherHomeStatus() == false) ? valid = false : valid);
        ((validateSortCode() == false) ? valid = false : valid);
        ((validateCareLeaverMessage() == false) ? valid = false : valid);

        return valid; //returns false in JavaScript debugger on Chrome
    }
}
```

Web Forms .aspx

```
<form id="Application" runat="server">
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AllValidation" ClientValidationFunction="validateForm"></asp:CustomValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="SaveLSFApplication" runat="server" Text="Submit Application" OnClick="saveApplication" ValidationGroup="AllValidation" />
</form>
```

WebForms .aspx.vb

```
Sub saveApplication(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Page.IsValid Then
        '--- do logic
    End If
End Sub
```

I know just client side validation isn't good enough, but it's for parts of the form that are non-optional only when a specific criteria has been met, i.e. when a user selects "Other" in drop down box and we want them to put in a reason in a text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this issue myself. Even though the JavaScript function was returning false, this means nothing in the context of a `CustomValidator` control. In order to prevent the form from submitting, the `CustomValidator` evaluates the property `IsValid`. If `IsValid` is `false`, then the form will not submit.

Here is the amended JavaScript function to reflect this change:

```
function validateForm(sender, args) { //added two function parameters
    if (document.getElementById("DDApplicationID").selectedIndex > 0
        && document.getElementById("div_applicationType").style.display != "none") {
        return true;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("DDApplicationID").selectedIndex > 0) {
        var valid = true;

        ((validateTrainStation() == false) ? valid = false : valid);
        ((validateSupportType() == false) ? valid = false : valid);
        ((validateHomeStatus() == false) ? valid = false : valid);
        ((validateOtherNationality() == false) ? valid = false : valid);
        ((validateOtherHomeStatus() == false) ? valid = false : valid);
        ((validateSortCode() == false) ? valid = false : valid);
        ((validateCareLeaverMessage() == false) ? valid = false : valid);

        args.IsValid = valid; //no longer returning valid
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've added two function parameters, `sender` and `args`. Then, instead of simply returning `valid`, I'm now setting the property `IsValid` of the `args` parameter to the value of `valid`. So, if `valid` is `false`, then `IsValid` is false. This `IsValid` is then evaluated which then prevents the form from continuing to submit.